# Can someone tell me what an "Editing context" is and how to get there?

Tags: edit-mode, text-object

I am using version 2.73 under Windows7.

This refers to page http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/texts/introduction.html

One can read at the top in the box labelled "Reference",

"Panel: Curve and Surface, Font and Char (Editing context, F9)"

I am in Edit mode (which I gather is not the same thing as "Editing context") and F9 does absolutely nothing for me.

Nowhere in the properties window can I see anything like "Curve and Surface"??

I can find a panel called "Font" but neither "Char" nor "Font and Char"

Help!!

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: you are looking at DOC of blender 2.4

Comment: @Chebhou Those are the modern docs, but they are still a bit under construction ;) Bernard I don't see any shortcut in blender which consists of *just* F9, and none relating to "editing contexts". Sounds like an outdated piece of the 2.4 manual slipped into the modern docs. What exactly are you trying to do? Perhaps we can find the 2.7 equivalent.

Comment: I hope you won't find this too cutting, but what I'm trying to do is

Comment: I hope you won't find this too cutting, but what I'm trying to do is use the manual! To my personal taste an incomplete manual is better than an erroneous one. I am fabulously impressed by Blender's capabilities but I think it fair to say that it has a very steep learning curve and errors like this don't help.<br> But to answer the question asked, I want to master text so I can extrude text onto&from a curve surface (I know there are youtube videos on this but I momentarily don-t have access to them).

Comment: @BernardHigonnet The [manual is a community project](http://blender.org/manual/about/contribute.html), and has just recently been transferred from the old wiki system (which was far worse in terms of erroneous and disorganized information). So as you might expect there still old pages like this one floating around.. Not good. When you come across one, pointing it out and/or contributing fixes is most welcome! I've already taken the liberty of looking into this one. As for extruding text, the easiest way is by using the *extrude* slider in the curve panel: http://pasteall.org/pic/85686